# org.apache.stratos.cartridge.agent.exception.ParameterNotFoundExcepti on: Cannot find the value of required parameter: SERVICE_NAME

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

could anyone give some hint?

run startos based on openstack,

on the stratos log file (install/apache-stratos-default/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log, report ip allocation error

```
TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2015-07-06 06:17:47,541]  INFO {org.apache.stratos.autoscaler.message.receiver.topology.AutoscalerTopologyEventReceiver} - 
 Member stat context has been removed successfully: [member] appserver.appserver.wso2.com.d9f30529a-b143-4dcc-bd73-91990b20c5af {org.apache.str
atos.autoscaler.message.receiver.topology.AutoscalerTopologyEventReceiver}
TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2015-07-06 06:17:52,226]  INFO {org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl} -  Instance is success
fully starting up. MemberContext [memberId=appserver.appserver.wso2.com.dfeb2a572-1d31-4928-a069-62d5c277cea0, nodeId=regionOne/cadb605e-8bef-4
54c-ada0-d65b1ccae773, clusterId=appserver.appserver.wso2.com.d, cartridgeType=appserver, privateIpAddress=null, publicIpAddress=null, allocate
dIpAddress=null, initTime=1436163460469, lbClusterId=lb.lb.ppaas.wso2.com.domain, networkPartitionId=openstack] {org.apache.stratos.cloud.contr
oller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl}
TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2015-07-06 06:17:52,395] ERROR {org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.iaases.OpenstackNovaIaas} -  Failed to allocate an IP a
ddress. {org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.iaases.OpenstackNovaIaas}
TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2015-07-06 06:17:52,395] ERROR {org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl} -  Error occurred whil
e allocating an ip address. MemberContext [memberId=appserver.appserver.wso2.com.dfeb2a572-1d31-4928-a069-62d5c277cea0, nodeId=regionOne/cadb60
5e-8bef-454c-ada0-d65b1ccae773, clusterId=appserver.appserver.wso2.com.d, cartridgeType=appserver, privateIpAddress=null, publicIpAddress=null,
 allocatedIpAddress=null, initTime=1436163460469, lbClusterId=lb.lb.ppaas.wso2.com.domain, networkPartitionId=openstack] {org.apache.stratos.cl
oud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl}
org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.exception.CloudControllerException: Failed to allocate an IP address.
        at org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.iaases.OpenstackNovaIaas.associateAddress(OpenstackNovaIaas.java:259)
        at org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl$IpAllocator.run(CloudControllerServiceImpl.java:669)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2015-07-06 06:17:53,371]  INFO {org.apache.stratos.autoscaler.PartitionContext} -  Pending state of member: lb.lb.ppaas.wso
2.com.domain3d5be5d6-c349-49ff-9cde-ab246dae7f56 is expired. Adding as an obsoleted member. {org.apache.stratos.autoscaler.PartitionContext}
TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2015-07-06 06:19:03,606]  INFO {org.apache.stratos.autoscaler.PartitionContext} -  Pending state of member: appserver.appse
rver.wso2.com.df69b8216-d8d8-4ca2-9aed-8e412639532e is expired. Adding as an obsoleted member. {org.apache.stratos.autoscaler.PartitionContext}
TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2015-07-06 06:19:22,048]  INFO {org.apache.stratos.autoscaler.client.cloud.controller.CloudControllerClient} -  Terminating
 instance via cloud controller: [member] lb.lb.ppaas.wso2.com.domain3d5be5d6-c349-49ff-9cde-ab246dae7f56 {org.apache.stratos.autoscaler.client.
cloud.controller.CloudControllerClient}
TID: [0] [STRATOS] [2015-07-06 06:19:22,120] ERROR {org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerServiceImpl} -  Termination failed.
 Invalid Member Id: lb.lb.ppaas.wso2.com.domain3d5be5d6-c349-49ff-9cde-ab246dae7f56 {org.apache.stratos.cloud.controller.impl.CloudControllerSe
rviceImpl}
```

on the node , in /var/log/apache-stratos/cartridge-agent.log, report:Cannot find the value of required parameter: SERVICE_NAME

```
2015-06-30 14:40:34,032 [-] [main] ERROR Main java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.stratos.cartridge.agent.exception.ParameterNotFoundExcepti
on: Cannot find the value of required parameter: SERVICE_NAME
2015-06-30 14:40:34,051 [-] [Thread-0]  WARN EventPublisherPool Event publisher instance not found in pool: [topic] instance-status
2015-07-06 17:03:26,902 [-] [main]  INFO CartridgeAgentConfiguration Cartridge agent configuration initialized
2015-07-06 17:03:27,281 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO CartridgeAgent Cartridge agent started
2015-07-06 17:03:27,339 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO CartridgeAgent Instance notifier event message receiver thread started
2015-07-06 17:03:27,356 [-] [Thread-4]  INFO InstanceNotifierEventMessageDelegator Instance notifier event message delegator started
2015-07-06 17:03:29,408 [-] [Thread-10]  INFO TopologyEventMessageDelegator Topology event message delegator started
2015-07-06 17:03:29,454 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO CartridgeAgent Tenant event message receiver thread started
2015-07-06 17:03:29,493 [-] [Thread-13]  INFO TenantEventMessageDelegator Tenant event message delegator started
2015-07-06 17:03:29,545 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO CartridgeAgentEventPublisher Publishing instance started event
2015-07-06 17:03:29,589 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO CartridgeAgentEventPublisher Instance started event published
2015-07-06 17:03:29,590 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO ExtensionUtils Waiting for complete topology event...
2015-07-06 17:03:34,590 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO ExtensionUtils Waiting for complete topology event...
2015-07-06 17:03:39,590 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO ExtensionUtils Waiting for complete topology event...
2015-07-06 17:03:44,591 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO ExtensionUtils Waiting for complete topology event...
2015-07-06 17:03:49,591 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO ExtensionUtils Waiting for complete topology event...
2015-07-06 17:03:54,592 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO ExtensionUtils Waiting for complete topology event...
2015-07-06 17:03:59,725 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO ExtensionUtils Waiting for complete topology event...
2015-07-06 17:04:00,324 [-] [Thread-13]  INFO CompleteTenantMessageProcessor Tenant initialized
2015-07-06 17:04:00,401 [-] [Thread-10]  INFO CompleteTopologyMessageProcessor Topology initialized
2015-07-06 17:04:00,401 [-] [Thread-10] ERROR ExtensionUtils Member id not found in topology [member] lb.lb.ppaas.wso2.com.domaind790ef20-8fff-
4c8a-b762-e770073ffa19
2015-07-06 17:04:00,420 [-] [Thread-10] ERROR ExtensionUtils Could not execute complete topology extension
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.stratos.cartridge.agent.util.ExtensionUtils.addPayloadParameters(ExtensionUtils.java:103)
        at org.apache.stratos.cartridge.agent.util.ExtensionUtils.executeCompleteTopologyExtension(ExtensionUtils.java:429)
        at org.apache.stratos.cartridge.agent.extensions.DefaultExtensionHandler.onCompleteTopologyEvent(DefaultExtensionHandler.java:345)
        at org.apache.stratos.cartridge.agent.CartridgeAgent$7.onEvent(CartridgeAgent.java:325)
        at org.apache.stratos.messaging.listener.EventListener.update(EventListener.java:42)
        at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:159)
        at org.apache.stratos.messaging.event.EventObservable.notifyEventListeners(EventObservable.java:51)
        at org.apache.stratos.messaging.message.processor.topology.CompleteTopologyMessageProcessor.process(CompleteTopologyMessageProcessor.ja
va:133)
        at org.apache.stratos.messaging.message.processor.MessageProcessorChain.process(MessageProcessorChain.java:60)
        at org.apache.stratos.messaging.message.receiver.topology.TopologyEventMessageDelegator.run(TopologyEventMessageDelegator.java:77)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-06 17:04:04,725 [-] [Thread-1]  INFO DefaultExtensionHandler [start server extension] complete topology event received
```

the boot.sh configure with conf.sh as following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Copyright 2005-2013 WSO2, Inc. http://www.wso2.org
#
#  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#  limitations under the License.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Pack files
export CONFIG_MB="true"
export ACTIVE_MQ_DISTRIBUTION=apache-activemq-5.9.1-bin.tar.gz # Relavent activemq distribution
export ACTIVE_MQ_EXTRACTED=apache-activemq-5.9.1 # Extracted activemq distribution folder name

export JAVA_FILE_DISTRUBUTION=jdk-7u75-linux-x64.tar.gz # Relevant JDK distribution
export JAVA_NAME_EXTRACTED=jdk1.7.0_75 # Extracted JDK folder name

export MYSQL_CONNECTOR=mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar # Relevant MySQL connector
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
# General configuration
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME:-}
export log_path=/var/log/apache-stratos
export stratos_domain="test.com"
export machine_ip="192.168.100.19"
export host_user="ubuntu"
export SLEEPTIME=30
export PPAAS_PORT=9443
export BAM_PORT=9444
export IS_PORT=9445
export CEP_PORT=9446
export GITBLIT_PORT=9418

# Puppet master configuration
export skip_puppet=""
export puppet_external="n"
export puppet_external_ip=""
export puppet_external_host=""

# cep as a separate profile
export separate_cep="n"

# IaaS configuration
export iaas="os"
# Region Name
export region="regionOne"
# Cartridge base image
export cartridge_base_img_id="bcac997c-b64b-412a-9d01-039db2f1a7e1"



# OpenStack
export os_identity="WSO2_TEST:mxx"
export os_credentials="000000"
export os_jclouds_endpoint="http://192.168.11.131:5000/v2.0"
export os_keypair_name="mxx"
export os_security_groups="default"

# EC2
export ec2_vpc=""
export ec2_identity=""
export ec2_credentials=""
export ec2_identity=""
export ec2_credentials=""
export ec2_owner_id=""
export ec2_keypair_name=""
export ec2_security_groups=""
export ec2_availability_zone=""
export ec2_security_group_ids=""
export ec2_subnet_id=""
#export ec2_associate_public_ip_address="true"
export ec2_associate_public_ip_address="false"

# vCloud
export vcloud_identity=""
export vcloud_credentials=""
export vcloud_jclouds_endpoint=""

# MySQL configuration
export setup_mysql="y"
export mysql_host="192.168.100.19"
export mysql_port="3306"
export mysql_uname="root"
export mysql_password="root"

#/etc/hosts mapping
export using_etc_host_mapping="y"

# WSO2 PPaaS services
export as_enabled="y"
export bps_enabled="n"
export esb_enabled="n"
export greg_enabled="n"
export is_enabled="n"
export apim_enabled="n"

# Worker Manager deployment
export as_worker_mgt_enabled="n"
export bps_worker_mgt_enabled="n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a problem with IP allocation. Have you added a property named defaultFloatingIpPool in cloud-controller.xml to specify the name of the floating IP pool to be used? If not, you need to add it to $PPAAS_HOME/install/apache-stratos-default/repository/conf/cloud-controller.xml and restart stratos. To restart stratos, you need to run `sh bin/stratos.sh stop`, wait for sometime and run `sh bin/stratos.sh start`from $PPAAS_HOME/install/apache-stratos-default directory.

```html
<iaasProviders>
<iaasProvider type="openstack" name="openstack specific details">
...
<property name="autoAssignIp" value="true"/>
<property name="defaultFloatingIpPool" value="public"/>
</iaasProvider>
</iaasProviders>
```